# How can i do a Count of Collection using Asp.net , Web API 2 and OData v4

Tags: collections, count, odata

I want to order results based on a count of collection using Asp.net, web api2 and OData v4.

My url is: `url/odata/groupeclients?$expand=Client&$orderby=Client/$count`

I get this error :

> "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The parent value for a
>   property access of a property '$count' is not a single value. Property
>   access can only be applied to a single value."

Is this supported in Web API OData? If not, is there any alternative solution?

Regards,
Hayfa

Comment: formatted a bit. might still require more information by OP (such as examples; code snippets; etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently supported; there's an [open issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/194).

As a workaround, you could define an OData function bound to `groupeclients` that explicitly performs the expansion and ordering. Something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult OrderByClientCount()
{
    return this.Ok(data.Include(e => e.Client).OrderBy(e => e.Client.Count));
}
```

Note that this code is untested and may not even be possible if your IQueryable data source does not support `Include` (or its equivalent).

Comment: Thanks  a lot ,it's a solution in backend but i want to call count in the request in frontend